# Convert data frame to table in Python to use in ChiSquare

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics

I am a novice in Python. I have excel data in tabular format as below
| Category | Lung cancer | Bronchitis | Cough |
| -------- | ----------- |----------- | ----- |
| Smoker   | 50          | 80         | 50    |
| not-s    | 2           | 30         | 45    |

I want to conduct a chi squared analysis to find whether disease is independent of category. All the chi squared tutorials I am referring to, convert raw data to contingency table but I already have a contingency table like data.
Should I load it as a contingency table? If so, how do I do that so that row index is category. If I load it as a data frame, how do I convert it to a table?

thanks!

I initially tried to convert data frame to contingency table but realized that my data does not require that conversion. I am guessing I just need to find out a way to convert this to a table. And then implement chi squared functions.